# Excel a change in cell value inserts a "S" in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have pasted worksheet1. Notice the columns. The one to be monitored is under header Description and Healthman. Once a change occurs in under column Change a S is inserted. E.g Spectacle Frame changes to Spec Frame, we insert S under Change. The change column is original empty. Under Healthman when price changes a P is inserted under Change column.  When a product is to be deleted i.e delete row a X is inserted under Change. When a row is inserted since i was comparing with a hidden sheet cell by cell thats the reason why i the hidden sheet was updated. i tried the previous code it is not working and thought of pasting the sheet for your review.
        Legend: P=PRICE CHANGE
        N = NEW   X = DELETED   S = DESCRIPTION
        Code    Change  Description               HEALTHMAN

```
    40501       Spectacle Frame             
    40609       Sunglasses              
    40525   S   Ready Made Optical              
    41008       Spectacle Case              
    43025   P   Transfer - Zyl or Metal  Frame  198.00          
    43126   P   Transfer - Nylon Supra Frame    314.00          
    43136   P   Transfer - Rimless Frame    359.00
```

Answer (score 5):

While working with `Worksheet_Change` you have to ensure 2 things.

**1)** Appropriate error handling is a must

**2)** Switch off `.EnableEvents` to avoid the possibility of an endless loop.

**ASSUMPTIONS**

**1)** You want to capture change in Cell `A1`

**2)** You want to display "S" in `A2`

So please change as applicable in the below code.

**CODE**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A2").Value = "S"
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Is this what you are trying?

This goes in "ThisWorkbook" Code area.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Dim hiddenSheet As Worksheet

   Set hiddenSheet = Me.Worksheets.Add
   hiddenSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

   On Error Resume Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Sheets("HiddenSheet").Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   On Error GoTo 0

   hiddenSheet.Name = "HiddenSheet"

   Sheet1.Range("A1:D15").Copy hiddenSheet.Range("A1:D15")
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Sheets("HiddenSheet").Delete
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

and this goes in the relevant sheet area

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:D15")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim old_value

        Application.EnableEvents = False

        old_value = Sheets("HiddenSheet").Range(Target.Address).Value

        If Target.Value <> old_value Then
            '~~> Change 1 to whatever offset that you want.
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "S"
        End If
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. The code that I gave will work but you have to modify it to suit your needs. The file that you uploaded doesn't have the codes that I gave. You have to use the above code and make necessary changes. once done then re upload the file so that i can see that you understand the code. Also this is getting too long. Can you delete all your comments above except the post which has the link? And I will do the same

Comment: You have pasted the code in the sheet "Prof fees History"? Shouldn't you be posting the code in "Sheet1"? And why are you using "C1:G15"? Is that the range that you want to trap?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have pasted it the sheet1. Yes I want to track description, healthman and optical assistant. I like the code. its working. i have aproblem though. when i just double click a cell in description without changing the description, it registers as a change and inserts an S same as in Healthman column. what must i do to counteract a double click not to be interpreted as a change.

Comment: And when there is both price change and description change it has to insert SP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Worksheet_Change event. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750361/excel-vba-multiple-cell-update-based-on-a-change-in-one-cell) and [that](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612).

Sample code to add to the Workseet - A3 will automatically change when you change another cell, with a specific behavior if that changed cell is A1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        Range("A3") = "You changed A1"
    ElseIf Target.Address <> Range("A3").Address Then 'to prevent a change of A3 to trigger an update
        Range("A3") = "You changed another cell"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I notice that if I just click the cell without changing the value or text in it, it inserts a value "S" in the next cell. is there a way i can keep or store the original value in a hidden worksheet and compare it with the cell value on exit of the cell. This way i can differentiate a genuine change from a mouse click.